# Sending push notifications from client

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, push-notification

I have several clients that want me to create an app and after it has been published in the App Store they want to have remote control over the iOS feature of push notifications - they want to send custom text etc. through the app. I'm totally new to this topic so I'd like to ask the question of how this can be done.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://urbanairship.com/

Comment: @AdilSoomro No, no server at all. Thinking about renting one online

Comment: At least three frameworks show up upon [Googling "simpleapns"](https://www.google.com/search?q=simpleapns), five on PyPI matching ["apns"](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=apns), and [Easy APNs](http://www.easyapns.com/) is popular if you like something backed by PHP, MySQL, and cronjobs. Code quality varies, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need your own web server before getting started.  Also, to allow your clients to send notifications, you'll have to have a website for them to post their messages to.  If you need a web server, I've had good experiences with maxiumumasp as a provider.  Here's a link:

http://www.maximumasp.com/products/virtualDedicated/default.aspx

Apple has really good documentation on push notifications here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

Please let me know if you have other specific questions after reading this.

Comment: You don't need your own web server, you need your own infrastructure - that's a non-trivial problem, even if you're buying the bits from AWS/Azure/AppEngine.  Putting this on a dedicated VM like you posted would be insane.  And you've now inserted your own infrastructure into a critical path for customers; most people think of the cost of that as somewhere around "catastrophic."  The Apple link is about Apple's normal push service; it's a tiny part of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need a server side application for Push Notifications.

Fortunately, there are lots of ready and FREE push providers which can help here and save your time

For example, [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/), they have a great and simple iOS guide on pushes https://developers.connectycube.com/ios/push-notifications

It also works cross-platform: iOS-Android-Web

Also, one of the day-to-day issue is APNS certificate generation. There is a dead simple guide how to do it https://developers.connectycube.com/ios/how-to-create-apns-certificate

Answer (score 1):

To be honest the simplest way of using push notifications is to use a service such as Urban airship.

I'm no expert on the subject but im sure that the terms in the app store have changed in regards to push notifications. So just make sure they are not sending out marketing spam etc.

Comment: Wow, but this one seems to costly - about 200$ a month! Aren't there any free/cheap solutions?

Comment: Not that im aware of, I think that they offer pay as you go solutions too. Not cheap but from experience it works and very easy to set up.